# Entity Framework returning distinct records after join

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Consider we have these two entities and one custom object :

```
    public class  Entiy1
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int DestinationId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string JobTitle { get; set; }
}

public class Entiy2
{
    [Key]
    public int DestinationId { get; set; }
    public int DestinationName { get; set; }


}
public class EntityDTO
{
    public int DestinationName { get; set; }
    public int DestinationId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string JobTitle { get; set; }
}
```

Data is something like this :

> Entity1 : 
>  Id=1 , DestinationId=1,Name=Name1,JobTitle=Job1
>   Id=2 , DestinationId=1,Name=Name2,JobTitle=Job2
>  Id=3 ,
>   DestinationId=2,Name=Name3,JobTitle=Job3
>  Id=4 ,
>   DestinationId=2,Name=Name4,JobTitle=Job4
>  Id=5 ,
>   DestinationId=2,Name=Name5,JobTitle=Job5
>   Entity 2:
>   DestinationId=1 , DestinationName=Destination1
>   DestinationId=2 , DestinationName=Destination2

How can I select distinct destinationId and select Name and JobTitle from Entity1 then join them with Entity2  to fetch destination name and returning them as EntityDTO ?

Comment: @GertArnold I've changed class definitions and added sample data.

Comment: So if you select distinct `DestinationId`s you're going to miss some names and job titles in the end result. Is that OK?

Comment: Yes it's ok . This is just a test. I want to check how select distinct of a column after or before join

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to do it:

```
var query = from e1 in
    (from e1 in entities1
        group e1 by e1.DestinationId into grp
        select grp.First())
    join e2 in entities2 on e1.DestinationId equals e2.DestinationId
    select new EntityDTO 
            { 
                DestinationId = e1.DestinationId, 
                DestinationName = e2.DestinationName,
                Name = e1.Name,
                JobTitle = e1.JobTitle
            } ;
```

The trick is the `group by` and then taking the first element of the grouping. This is also referred to as "distinct by" that a library like [MoreLinq](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) provides out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

Using LINQ extensions, I'm more of a fan of them:

```
var results = entityList1
            .GroupBy(e => e.DestinationId)
            .Select(e => e.First())
            .Join(entityList2, e1 => e1.DestinationId, e2 => e2.DestinationId, (e1, e2) => 
                new EntityDTO
                {
                    DestinationId = e1.DestinationId,
                    DestinationName = e2.DestinationName,
                    JobTitle = e1.JobTitle,
                    Name = e1.Name
                });
```

Same thing as Gert's anwser really.  You **can** use `Distinct` but, you would have to inherit from `IEquatible<T>` and implement the `Equals` method and override the `GetHashCode` method to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the LINQ join operator like this:

```
var results = from e1 in context.Entity1s
              join e2 in context.Entity2s
              on e1.DestinationId equals e2.DestinationId
              select new EntityDTO
              {
                  DestinationId = e1.DestinationId,
                  Name = e1.Name,
                  JobTitle = e1.JobTitle,
                  DestinationName = e2.DestinationName
              };
```

Comment: Where is distinct ? We may have multiple records with same destinationId on Entity1 . we want to prevent duplicates using Distinct . something like this : Select Distinct destinationId ...

Comment: If you have multiple entities with the same destination ID, then which name and job title would you want listed from the source table? The first? The last? Do you want to aggregate them somehow? Your data doesn't line up with your expected result.

Comment: I don't have DestinationName on first Entity, That's why i want to joint entities to have DestinationName on result.

Comment: I get that. Perhaps you need to add some sample data as well as the results you're looking to achieve so I can better understand the shape of your data.

Comment: I see your source data, but what results are you expecting? The sensible result is returned by my answer...

Comment: Your query returns records with duplicate destinationId .