# How to retrive distinct rows based on a column when join in entity framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, join

I want to join 2 tables and retrieve distinct rows based on 2 columns in entity framework.

I have read posts on web including SO.

In the code below,
1. I join 2 tables based on `CurrentTurnID` key
2. I filter the table by the features that I want
3. I filter the table by setting conditions on selected features
4. I select a column to calculate the sum of all it's value

I need to retrieve records that have the same `CurrentTurnID` just once. Here's my code:

```
int services = Convert.ToInt32(database.Tbl_CurrentTurn.AsNoTracking()
            .Join(database.Tbl_pay.AsNoTracking(), f => f.CurrentTurnID,
               s => s.CurrentTurnID, (f, s) => new
               {
                   f.CurrentTurnOfficialID,
                   f.CurrentTurnID,
                   f.SickID,
                   f.Remove,
                   f.Payment,
                   f.ServicePayment,
                   s.isDeposit
               })
            .Where(w => w.SickID == SickId && w.Remove != true && w.Payment == true && w.isDeposit != true)
            .Select(s => s.ServicePayment).DefaultIfEmpty(0).Sum());
```

If I add `Distinct()` after `Select()` statement, it would consider the `ServicePayment` to filter distinct rows.

**Update:** [The Image is attached to my Dropbox.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5usxnbftndkdlz8/Ali.png?dl=0)
The 2nd and the 3rd records have the same `CurrentTurnID` value. So I want to consider just one of them. Then sum up records on `ServicePayment` column. Please notice that other columns are different in these 2 records.

Comment: Did you also try it with GroupBy?

Comment: How should I use `GroupBy`? I couldn't make appropriate aggregation function.

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to sum up all records on `ServicePaymant`, that have the same `CurrentTurnID`?

Comment: No, I want to sum up the column `ServicePayment ` in all rows, but consider the rows that have same `CurrentTurnID` just once.

Comment: are you getting "duplicate" rows because of a fault with your join condition?

Comment: Take a look at this post: [Entity Framework returning distinct records after join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16799008/entity-framework-returning-distinct-records-after-join)

Comment: Not exactly duplicated, some columns are different in near-duplicated records.

Comment: Can you post some examples?

Comment: @Leon, yes I have tried these answers also. I have some errors using them.

Comment: @CaiusJard, I have updated my question and added an example.

Comment: Can yousay "where type = 4"? The "duplicate" rows seem to be coming from one table - will filtering them down a bit more, work out? The reason I ask this is that usually when someone comes saying "i'm getting duplicates from my DB what can I do?" - the answer is not to use Distinct to take them out, it's to filter better so they don't creep in in the first place. There should be some rule you want to implement, to define only the rows you want to keep such as "only the latest row" or "only rows of type 4"

Comment: @CaiusJard, No I can't. The `type` column show the way patient has payed for his/her payment, e.g. "in cash" or "by card". there may be some different way for one payment. For example if the patient has payed his bill with 2 different card, there are 2 records with `type = 4`. Or even may be no payment with `type = 4` ate all.

Comment: It was an example - what is the rule you require for which rows you want? Rules are like "only the latest row as determined by the paymentdate column" or "only rows where columnx is 'valueY' " or "the max paymentvalue per paymentID". If you're at a point where you're saying "there is no rule.. there are just these extra rows that are useless and cause me a problem but have no purpose" it's time to implement rules to prevent them appearing in the first place

Comment: I need all records that passed through the filter using `where` condition. Just removing duplicated records based on `CurrentTurnID`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a `GroupJoin` to get that information without the need for `Distinct` like this:

```
int services = Convert.ToInt32(database.Tbl_CurrentTurn.AsNoTracking()
        .GroupJoin(database.Tbl_pay.AsNoTracking(), f => f.CurrentTurnID,
           s => s.CurrentTurnID, (f, s) => new {f, s})
         .SelectMany(x=> x.s.DefaultIfEmpty(), (f, s) => new
           {
               f.CurrentTurnOfficialID,
               f.CurrentTurnID,
               f.SickID,
               f.Remove,
               f.Payment,
               ServicePayment = s != null ? s.ServicePayment : 0,
               s.isDeposit
           })
        .Where(w => w.SickID == SickId && w.Remove != true && w.Payment == true 
               && w.isDeposit != true)
        .Select(x=> x.ServicePayment).Sum());
```

This may not compile correctly since I don't have all the variables and a small example I can use to test this.

You should be able to get this to work with very few changes. I use a similar query to get a list for a cost report.